# The point of intersection of the four space diagonals of a general parallelepiped, the centroid

Tags: polyhedra, solid-geometry, centroid

I know that the centroid of a parallelogram is the intersection of the diagonals, but is it true that the centroid of a parallelepiped is the intersection of the space diagonals?

I'm talking about the general case of parallelepiped. Thank you

Comment: Start with a cuboid, and then skew it

Comment: Yes, it's true.

Comment: That's an obvious consequence of central symmetry.